# Split column and select value

Tags: u-sql

I have a column in my input data which contains multiple values seperated by a comma. Example:

[my_list]
'1,123,233,400,500'

I want to select the rows where [my_list] contains '123'.

What I have tried is:

new SQL.ARRAY(my_list.Split(',')) == '123'

'123' IN my_list.Split(','))

But no success. I'm not really sure how to solve it. Could someone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@table = 
SELECT * FROM 
    ( VALUES
    (1, "1,123,233,400,500"),
    (2, "123,233,400,500"),
    (3, "1,123"),
    (4, "1,233,400,500"),
    (5, "1,   123   ,233,400,500")
    ) AS T(id, my_list);

@result1 =
    SELECT * FROM @table
    WHERE my_list LIKE "%123%";

@result2 =
    SELECT * FROM @table
    WHERE new SQL.ARRAY<string>(my_list.Replace(" ", "").Split(',')).Contains("123");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    String.Concat(",", String.Concat([my_list], ",")) LIKE "%,123,%";
```

This trick compares `,1,123,233,400,500,` against `%,123,%`, i.e. it checks for `123` in *any* position (start, middle, or end).

While this option may fix your immediate problem, a better long term solution is to not store CSV data in your SQL tables.

Comment: Thanks! And is this as fast as using a kind of split or SQL.ARRAY function?

Answer (score 1):

And just for the fun of it, here is another way to address the same request using CROSS APPLY EXPLODE:

```
@table = 
  SELECT * FROM 
    ( VALUES
      (1, "1,123,233,400,500"),
      (2, "123,233,400,500"),
      (3, "1,123"),
      (4, "1,233,400,500"),
      (5, "1,   123   ,233,123,500")
    ) AS T(id, my_list);

@result =
  SELECT DISTINCT id, my_list 
  FROM @table CROSS APPLY EXPLODE (my_list.Split(new char[] {',', ' '})) AS x(item)
  WHERE item == "123";

OUTPUT @result TO "/output/result.csv" USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader:true);
```